# Unreal condition with Imparfait and Conditionnel Passé

Tags: conditionnel, conditions

I know there are 3 types of unreal conditions in French:

1. Present: Si + Imparfait + Conditionnel Present

Used for an unreal condition in the present. However the result might become real if the circumstances change.

2. Past: Si + Plus-que-parfait + Conditionnel Passé

Used for an unreal condition in the past, the result can't become real anymore.

3. Past: Si + Plus-que-parfait + Conditionnel Présent

Used for an unreal condition in the past, the result can't become real anymore, and is relevant for the present.

I was wondering, what is the form Si + Imparfait + Conditionnel Passé used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause must be before the effect. So this combination doesn't work most of the time. However, using the "imparfait" in the condition may also insist on the fact that you know that this condition is so unlikely that it will never be true. For example :

```
Si j'étais riche, je t'aurais offert un magnifique cadeau.
```

In this case, you state that you are not rich, and you believe that this will never be real (you don't know the futur).

Comment: I would still have used *Si j'avais été riche, je t'aurais offert un magnifique cadeau*, or maybe *Eussé-je été riche, je t'eusse offert un magnifique cadeau* ;-)

Comment: Je dis bien que ce n'est pas la meilleure construction, puisqu'elle va à l'encontre de la concordance des temps. Cependant, les "temps" dans les phrases conditionnelles peuvent également jouer un rôle quant à la probabilité de l'action. J'ai par ailleurs déjà rencontré cette construction, lorsque l'état perdure, mais je n'ai malheureusement pas de citation en tête.